# make image url and get image from url and store image to database and send image to user via url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need code for how to receive a image from url? and how to store database to that image? and send the image to called user via url?
I am using servlets and jsp.

Comment: I see 3 questions with no attempt to solve any of them.  Other people might want to know: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  For my part, voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: Pure code writing request are considered off-topic and would be closed. Show us what you tried. Come back with a error or something.

Comment: Is anyother question left, still?

Answer (score 2):

**I need code for how to receive a image from url?**

Here It is:

```
URL lenna = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png");
Image img = ImageIO.read(lenna);
```

**and how to store database to that image?**

You can upload it on server and can store that imagepath to Database, Storing an whole image is not a good idea.

You can refer to [`Jakarta Commons FileUpload`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) for file upload.

**and send the image to called user via url?**

After uploading file on server you can easily send that image url to user.

**I am using servlets and jsp.**

All of the above options are in `Java` Only... :)